# How to find frozen area in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to find out, in Excel VBA, what the frozen rows or columns of a sheet are? Ideally I'd like to do it without having to bring focus to the sheet.

What I want to do is find the row immediately below the frozen rows, clear everything below that, and start filling in data there.

Comment: Not without activating the sheet, no. You need the `activewindow.splitrow` and `splitcolumn` properties.